# Ways to defeat SSL

Tags: tls, sslstrip

I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibF36Yyeehw) in which the guy talks about ways to defeat SSL. But the video is 4 years old. I wanted to know if these attacks are relevant even now, or some updates have been made to tackle these.

The *two* different attacks(or tools) he talked about in the video are

- `SSL-Strip`: Its like man in the middle in certificate chain `or` in some cases without certificate chain. It can work by taking advantage of null-prefixed certificates.
- `SSL-Sniff`: Monitors the transition/redirection of webpage from http to https version.

I guess SSL-Strip attack should be relevant even now. I am a newbie to the ssl protocol, so forgive me if I have a wrong understanding of it. Any good reading materials on the same would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- sslstrip: This is a downgrade attack, i.e. browser is forced to use insecure HTTP instead of HTTPS. It is still possible, but can be mitigated by the server with [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), at least for supported browsers. Most current browsers support it, see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stricttransportsecurity) for more details.
- sslsniff: This is a man-in-the-middle attack. The browsers detected this already 4 years ago but now have mostly more strict warnings and when combined with HSTS the browser will not allow bypass of this warning anymore.

> Any good reading materials on the same would be appreciated.

For more details about mitigation techniques and their limits read about [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), [HPKP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Public_Key_Pinning) and how these techniques [helped to detect real attacks](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2011/08/iranian-man-middle-attack-against-google).